# If $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$ is derivable in $\sigma\in X\subset \mathbb{R}$ then $\sigma$ is an accumulation point of $X$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, derivatives

My book says that a function $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$ is derivable at point $\sigma\in X$ if there exists a function $\varphi_{\sigma}:X\to\mathbb{R}$ which is continuous at $\sigma$ such that $f(x)-f(\sigma)=\varphi_{\sigma}(x)(x-\sigma)$. My book says that since every function is continuous at a isolated point of its domain, then it only considers the derivatives of points of accumulation of the domain of $f$. So I'm curious to know if all the points in which $f$ have derivatives are points of accumulation of the domain.

Comment: what book are you following?

Comment: It is a brazilian book called "Introdução à Análise Matemática da Reta"(Introduction to Mathematical Analysis of the Line).

Comment: You may or may not define the derivative of a function at an isolated point depending on whether you like it or not. It simply makes no difference.

Comment: @CaveJohnson I have just discovered that this definition of derivative that I put into the question is called "Carathéodory Derivative". I'll research more about it.

Comment: You would find your definition of derivative to be a very fundamental concept after you have encountered some more advanced mathematical analysis. It's good that you are discovering this fact a bit earlier, good luck :-) But my answer to your question remains the same: defining derivative or not at isolated points makes no difference.

Comment: In case you are interested: your definition of derivatives is believed to be the correct one in a normed vector space, where the traditional "limit of quotient" does not work well since there is no quotient in such a space. Also, the proof of chain rule becomes much more natural under this definition. What makes this definition so distinguished is that, it represents one of the most important idea in analysis and geometry, namely "local linearization".

Answer (score 0):

The derivative at a point $x_0$ is defined to be $\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}$. The condition $x\rightarrow x_0$, itself needs $x_0$ to be an accumulation point.

Comment: I'm in doubt now, because Atbey's answer makes sense. Could you take a look at it and see if it's really correct? I have not found anything wrong with what he wrote. If it is really correct, then we can conclude that the usual definition of a derivative is a definition restricted only to accumulation points, that is, it is not a general definition since it excludes isolated points.

Comment: As @Masacroso has already said, the limit in derivative is defined on a punctured neighborhood.

Answer (score 0):

$f$ has a derivative but rather trivial.

Let $\sigma$ be an isolated point and;
\begin{equation}
\varphi_\sigma(x) = 
\begin{cases}
\ \ \ \ \ a\quad &if \quad x=\sigma\\
\frac{f(x)-f(\sigma)}{x-\sigma} \quad &\quad\ \ \  \ o/w
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

where $a\in\mathbb{R}$. Now, $\varphi_\alpha$ is continous at $\sigma$ for any $a$ because $\sigma$  is an isolated point. Moreover, $f(x)-f(\sigma)=\varphi_\sigma(x)(x-\sigma)$ is satisfied again for any $a$.

Comment: I'm thinking about your answer. It makes sense, however it seems that the usual definition of derivatives using limits implies that there is no derivative of isolated points. However the definition of derivative that I put in the question shows otherwise.

Comment: The point is, you can always define $\varphi_\sigma$ as above(as it is the condition itself), but you want to make sure it is continuous at $\sigma$. When one considers accumulation point, then we can talk about limits but this is not possible for isolated points. Author defines it in such a way to avoid making definition only for accumulation points of the space, but then adds it is trivially satisfied for any isolated point. Since you can talk about continuous functions without notion of limit but only topologically, I like this definition more.

Answer (score 0):

A functional limit is defined on punctured neighborhoods of the variable, but there are no sequences that converges to $x_0$ in any punctured neighborhood of $x_0$, thus (by the sequential characterization of functional limits) a functional limit cannot be defined in an isolated point. Consequently any functional limit can be defined only in accumulation points.

Comment: But there is a sequence that converges to an isolated point $x_0$. It is the continuous sequence $(x_0)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$

Comment: this sequence doesnt exists in a punctured neighborhood of $x_0$ because $x_0$ doesnt belongs to this neighborhood.